# Email queue service for .NET

Tags: .net, email, message-queue

We're building an app that sends email using our clients' servers.  The servers have different settings in regards to how many emails can be sent per connection/per second/etc.

Can someone recommend a component for this so we don't have to build our own?  I came across MailBee Message Queue (http://www.afterlogic.com/products/message-queue), but I'd love to be able to compare it against something (or hear your experiences with it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used other products from Quiksoft before and found them to be good. They appear to have an [express SMTP server product](http://www.quiksoft.com/products/servers.asp).

Comment: This is an SMTP server which is not what we're looking for.

Comment: Well it turns out I just don't know much about SMTP!  Apparently this is what we want as we can setup the server to forward through another server (our clients' servers).